# Is working in Investment Bank as a Software Engineer haram?

Tags: software, banking

I’m a student and looking for jobs so i was wondering if working in such companies is haram as software engineer. I’m mostly confused by fatwas some say it’s haram, whistl some say it’s halal as we’re doing permissible work.

JazakAllah khair